# Change part of a string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is something simple, but I can't figure it out.

I have this HTML:

`<img src="/7290/9200572193_f95fb66c50_m.jpg" />`

Which I need to change to

`<img src="/7290/9200572193_f95fb66c50_b.jpg" />`

This isn't always the same image, but the `_m.jpg` and `_b.jpg` are. How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Are you just trying to replace "_m.jpg" by "_b.jpg" in a string or what ? If so it's a very simple use case for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Yes. I need to do this for multiple images, too, if that matters. I think I can figure that out, though, I just need help changing the `_m` to `_b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var imgSrc = "/7290/9200572193_f95fb66c50_m.jpg";
imgSrc = imgSrc.replace("_m.jpg", "_b.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help you:

```
$( "img" ).each(function() {
  var src = $( this ).attr( "src" );
  $( this ).attr( "src", src.replace( /_m\.(.*)$/, "_b.$1" ) );
});
```

This will not depend on the extension of your `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through "img" tags with `$("img").each(function(){ doStuff(); });`.  Change attributes with `attr("attribute","new_value")`, get attributes with `attr("attribute")`.  Replace with `replace("from","to")`.

```
$("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace("_m","_b"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, use[`.replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp). Such as:

```
"/7290/9200572193_f95fb66c50_m.jpg".replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');
/*  OR  */
var url = "/7290/9200572193_f95fb66c50_m.jpg";
url.replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg');
```

---

You use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) to loop through a group of elements. Thus you can use a simple selector like `$('img')` to select all images on the view and then make changes in the [`callback`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) method. You would then use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to both set and get the current `src` and change it using old fashioned [`.replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
$("img").each(function(i) {
    $(this).prop("src", $(this).prop("src").replace('_m.jpg', '_b.jpg'));
});
```

## Example

Comment: `prop` should be used for boolean values I believe, `attr` would be used to replace a source.

Comment: @tymeJV no, prop will work. prop changes how booleans are tested, but still reads "properties" of an element as much as `attr`

Comment: @tymeJV [Pretty good explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)